# I'm looking to have a <span> inside a <p> be underlined and fill the remainder space of the <p> tag

Tags: html, css

I'd like the underline of the `<span class="line-sm"></span>` to fill in the remainder of the `<p>` space and have a border-bottom.

Here's a mockup, with the red line being what I want the span to be:

[image: Mockup of what I'm looking for]

If the window shrinks, the span will also shrink. Sort of like "contain" for image backgrounds.

Here is the HTML I have:

```
  <p>
    <strong>What ACT score do you want? <span class="line-sm"></span></strong> 
  </p>
```

Any ideas if this is possible without the use of tables or some crazy workaround?

Thanks!

Comment: Trying adding a width: 100% to the span styling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you don`t want to use flexbox, try adding some pseudo elements:

CSS:

```
.line {
  position: relative;
  display: block;    
}

.line::before {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  border-bottom: solid red 2px;
  content: '';
  z-index: 0;
}

.text {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background: white;
  /* make some space with padding after text label */
  padding-right: 5px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

HTML:

```
<p>
  <span class="line">
    <span class="text">
      <strong>What ACT score do you want?</strong>
    </span>
  </span>
  <span class="line">
    <span class="text">
      Another line
    </span>
  </span>
</p>
```

[See codepen example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pQwvdL)

Answer (score 1):

You can use flexbox to allow the span to grow to fit its parent. I'd recommend closing the `strong` tag before the `span` in this case.

```css
p {
  display: flex;
}

p .line-sm {
  flex: 1;
  margin-left: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <strong>What ACT score do you want?</strong>
  <span class="line-sm"></span>
</p>
```

---

If you want to ensure the span doesn't collapse so far that it disappears, you could add a `min-width` to it:

```css
p {
  display: flex;
}

p .line-sm {
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 200px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <strong>What ACT score do you want?</strong>
  <span class="line-sm"></span>
</p>
```

Comment: This method seems to work, but if the paragraph text goes beyond one line, it doesn't show the span with the border-bottom :(

Comment: @user1301324 easy enough to fix - just put a `min-width` on the span. I'm not aware of any specific requirements other than what you've explained so far, so I wasn't going to complicate my example.

Comment: Fair point. I tried it, but it still doesn't seem to add the line at the bottom. It just disappears.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `:after` pseudo-class to display the line after your content.

```css
span.line-sm:after {
  margin: 0 0 0 10px;
  background-color: #000;
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1px;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <strong>What ACT score do you want? <span class="line-sm"></span></strong>
</p>
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but I want the width of it to be based on how much space is remaining on that line, not 50% of the paragraph.